# Retry in nunit not working when test times out

Tags: automated-testing, c#, nunit

I am using Timeout attribute for nunit test case as below:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestCases"), Retry(2), Timeout(10000)
public void test(){
    // Some code that runs for more than 10 seconds
}
```

I have gone through the documentation of nunit but it said that apart from assertion error, retry will not work but I have a situation where test times out.

I want this test to execute again as it is timing out but it executes only once using above code. Please help.

Comment: Let's get this person some help!

Comment: Thanks but no answer yet :(

Answer (score 2):

Retry only works on Assertion failures. You will have to write a custom Retry attribute that retries on Errors as well. Here is one way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319701/nunit-retry-on-exception-by-default